# Flex 3: Is it possible to use a remote image as the icon for a LinkButton?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

We are creating a LinkButton programmatically and would like to set it's icon to an image retrieved from the remote server rather than something embedded within the SWF.  The `.icon` property expects a `Class` but I can't figure out how to create one equivalent to an `@Embed` but from a dynamically generated URLRequest or URL String.

```
var myImage:Image = new Image();
myImage.source = "http://www.domain.com/img/1234.png";
myImage.width = 16;
myImage.height = 16;
myImage.scaleContent = true;

var myButton:LinkButton = new LinkButton();
myButton.label = "Some text"

// This is what I'm trying to figure out.
myButton.setStyle("icon", ???)
```

I'm probably missing something obvious - I've tried passing in the URL and `myImage` separately but both throw errors.  Stepping into the `setStyle()` method shows that the code is expecting a `Class` - so what do I pass in place of the ???

I can't embed the image itself because it's dynamic - the URL is different each time the software runs.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the buttonMode of a mx:Image to true then add a click event?

```
<mx:Image source="{imageSource}" buttonMode="true" click="action()" />
```

I'm not sure its possible without using an embedded images with a linkButton

[This](http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=42) might be worth a read

Edit... in AS3:

```
var img:Image = new Image();
img.source = "...";
img.buttonMode = true;
img.addEventListenever(MouseEvent.CLICK, funcName);
```

Comment: As I mentioned, we need to create the button programmatically - it's part of a Factory pattern that is manufacturing UI components based on certain states.  I'd prefer not to have to create a new MXML component simply for the purpose of binding the image - in the hopes that there is some easy way to set the image through code.  But thanks - it's is a reasonable suggestion and I'll try it if a code-based solution isn't possible.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the edit.  If we only needed the image you're right that this would work fine.  But we're looking to have a `LinkButton` to maintain a consistent look-n-feel with other components on the UI and it needs to include the icon, label text and the mouse-over interaction that a `LinkButton` offers out of the box - if we can just get the icon to be populated from a URL...

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of trying to set the style, you need to change the child object that holds the icon. You can access it by something like:

```
Var:Bitmap icon = myButton.getChildByName("upIcon") as Bitmap
```

It should be easy to replace the bitmapData in there with the one from a Loader.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, you'll want to use `button.setStyle('icon', img)`, where `img` is an image loaded via `Loader` class.

Answer (score 0):

for laalto,

this may be too late of an answer but somebody might find it useful or as a starting point to a solution to your problem. Have you tried referencing your image icon as a class? I don't know if this will work for an image which is in a dynamic URL but this worked for me:

```
[Embed("assets/LinkButton.png")]
private const linkButtonIcon:Class;
```

Then in your code:

```
myButton.setStyle("icon", linkButtonIcon);
```

See this example here:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/09/03/setting-the-icon-on-a-linkbutton-control-in-flex/

Answer (score -2):

```
<mx:Button id="example" label="Example" icon="{IconUtility.getClass(example, 'http://www.exampledomain.com/image.jpg')}" />
```

http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=42